# Formatting Date in Javascript as yyyy-mm-dd and passing it in Kettle

Tags: javascript, kettle

How do I return yesterday day in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd` using JavaScript and using 
the regular expression below.

```
((19|20)\d\d)-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

Answer (score 0):

Native JS date formatting is very primitive (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript?lq=1) for more details).

If you can, a better solution is to use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to make working with dates in JS much, much better.